# Making maven copy additional files inside the build jar (not resources but any file inside any package)?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, build

I have a package `org.myapp.mypackage` with some ruby files (`*.rb`) and I need to include them in the generated build jar *in the same package* along with the java class files.

How do I tell my friend Maven to do this?

*Note : No, I cannot copy to anywhere else, but thanks for suggesting. :)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can modify the resources section of the `<build>` bit of the POM:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>*.rb</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Or, the other answer (create the same package structure in `src/main/resources`) will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i understood the problem correctly, but if your Ruby files are packaged by maven and 
declared as a dependency, you can use the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to include the
contents into the resulting jar file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>org.myapp.mypackage:mypackage</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>org.myapp.mypackage:mypackage</artifact>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org/my/package/*.rb</include>
                        </includes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

Put them in the correct directory (src/main/resources in general) and
they should be bundled into the Jar properly. To put you *.rb files create the same dir structure under the src/main/resources folder.