# JBossAS [6.0.0.Final ] how to export sources of a project to deployment jar

Tags: java, jboss

I have an EJB project that has dependeny with Project B.

I am defining this dependency  in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>b</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using eclipse.When I add this ejb project as deployment to server, a jar is copied to deploy folder of Jboss.I want to  store source classes of B inside deployment jar.How can I do this?

Comment: By source classes, do you mean .class files or .java files?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to put the source file directly into the deployment artefact, but if your really want to do it, check out [this SO anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393404/making-maven-copy-additional-files-inside-the-build-jar-not-resources-but-any-f).

Generally, to attach sources to your build, check this [recipe](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Maven dependency plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

The specific goal you require would be unpack:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html

The *outputDirectory* in the configuration should be set to the same location as the classes for the EJB - this is usually */target/classes*. Note, you will want to run this in a Maven phase prior to *package* so that the classes are present before the jar is created.