# Maven. How to create .jar with local .txt files

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar

I use Intellij Idea.

Java-classes use `.txt` files which are placed in folder where `.java` files are situated. 
I created `.jar` file with maven and pom.xml. But there are no `.txt` in `.jar` file. 
How to add them there?

**UPDATED**:

I have such structure `src/main/java/Project-name/` for `.java` files. And `src/main/resources/`for `.txt` files. Within `.java` files I access files as `../../resources/filename.xml` and all works fine. But .jar-files created with maven  says:

```
Unable to open "../../resources/filename.xml"
```

How correctly should I declare filenames?

Comment: You can use maven resource plugin to create [custom resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393404/making-maven-copy-additional-files-inside-the-build-jar-not-resources-but-any-f)

Comment: @RazvanManolescu, no you don't.

Comment: The should be located in the `src/main/resources` folder and *not* in the `src/main/java` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are going against the convention. Java source goes to `src/main/java` but your resources must go to `src/main/resources`. The rest ist handled by Maven.